# Get file from disk in order to stream it as part of a HTTP response

Tags: javascript, http, node.js

I am writing HTTP server on top of Node.js, without using HTTP module.

Retrieving a GET message: `GET /www/index.html HTTP/1.1` should send a response with the file located at `/www/index.html`, same with images and other files.

Could anyone guide me to a javascript way to fetch the files from disk and add them to my HTTP response ?

My server should be able to support the following content types :

1. JavaScript: application/javascript
2. HTML: text/html
3. CSS: text/css
4. JPEG: image/jpeg
5. GIF: image/gif

Comment: HTTP server should support the following content types (HTTP Response header):

    JavaScript : application/javascript
    HTML: text/html
    CSS: text/css
    JPEG: image/jpeg
    GIF: image/gif

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the [`fs` module](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.3.1/api/fs.html#file_System) is what you are looking for.

It provides various function to open and read from files. A simple example :

```
fs.readFile('/etc/passwd', function (err, data) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log(data);
});
```

You can also consult this blog post about reading files with Node : [Different ways to read in files using node.js](http://onteria.wordpress.com/2011/06/02/different-ways-to-read-in-files-using-node-js/)

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
var fs = require('fs'),
    http = require('http'),
    path = require('path');
http.createServer(function(req,res){
   path.exists('./' + req.url, function(exists){
     if (!exists){ res.writeHead(404, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'}); res.end('not found'); }
     else {
       var read_stream = fs.createReadStream('./' + req.url);
       if (read_stream.readable){ res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type':'text/plain'}); }
       else { res.writeHead(500, {'Content-Type':'text/plain'}); res.end('Error Reading File'); }
       read_stream.on('data', function(data){ res.write(data); });
       read_stream.on('end', function(){ res.end(); fs.close(read_stream); });
     }
   }
}).listen(3030);
```

The main trick here is to use the readable stream of a file.